# Patch new record with lookup column Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

How to create a new record in SharePoint list with a lookup column from a button?

SharePoint list "tbl-one" has a lookup column "Contract" and other columns "Title" and "Payment".

```
Patch(
    tbl_one,
    Defaults(tbl_one),
    {
        Contract: {
            Value: "Test name"
        },
        Title: "16",
        Payment: 160,
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi, does below solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you have to pass the item `ID` from lookup parent list as well in Patch function.

**Example**:

```
Patch(
    'Site Inspections',
    LookUp('Site Inspections', ID=1),
    {
        BranchLocationLookUp: {
            Id: 2,
            Value: "Minneapolis, MN"
        }
    }
)
```

So, pass the item ID from your parent list.

Assuming your parent lookup list name is `Contracts` and primary lookup column from parent list is `Title`, you can use formula like:

```
Patch(
    tbl_one,
    Defaults(tbl_one),
    {
        Contract: {
            Id: LookUp(Contracts, Title="Test name", ID)
            Value: "Test name"
        },
        Title: "16",
        Payment: 160,
    }
)
```

**References**:

1. [PATCH A SharePoint LookUp Column In Power Apps](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-patch-function-examples-for-every-sharepoint-column-type/patch-a-sharepoint-lookup-column-in-power-apps/)
2. [How to patch a SharePoint Lookup Column?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-patch-a-SharePoint-Lookup-Column/td-p/24094)